# How to add a file to the .gitignore configuration

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a working project, but there is a file I accidentally pushed to the remote branch and I need to ignore it in the `.gitignore`.

This is the structure:

```
/project
  /app..
  | ...
  | ...
  /public
    | myFile.json
```

I added this entry on my `.gitignore` file:

```
...
/public/myFile.json
...
```

But it continues recognizing it as a outgoing file. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the file from git also as the old file is still tracked:

```
git rm --cached public/myFile.json
```

With the `--cached` the file will stay in your local copy.

Comment: other solution I just found is to delete the file, commit the changes on the gitignore and the deleted file, and then creating the deleted file again... it sounds like a tongue twister, but works